# What should be used to search a string across multiple fields of a single object? SOQL or SOSL

Tags: soql, query, performance, sosl

I want to search records for a particular object based on filter string that can match multiple fields on that object. This can be achieved via both SOQL and SOSL:

SOQL : using like operator, applying it on each of the columns in "OR"

SOSL: normal SOSL query on that 1 object.

Which is recommended approach? As per SF guidelines,

> Use SOQL to search in single object

> Use SOSL to search across objects and across fields.

But what to use if we have to search "across fields of a single object". Also, how can we search date fields? For example, `createddate` is `2022-02-09T11:33:17.000+0000` and my search string is `"2022"`, so it should return all records for that object whose created date falls in 2022.

Comment: I would say when it is possible to use SOQL, use SOQL, it is much more optimized.

Comment: Yes like @MariiaIllarionova mentioned, you can use SOQL when it is possible as it retrieves from only one object and it is optimized for such operation.

Regarding Date filtering, you can filter like : CALENDAR_YEAR(yourDateField) = 2022

Comment: @Praveen : it may not be year exactly. If user enters 12, it should return records where date is 12 or month is 12 or year is 12. Even time containing 12.

Comment: SOSL searches only in searchable fields - https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.search_fields_lex.htm&type=5, so standard CreatedDate is not searchable